# A specific linear operator between Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let B be the Banach space $B=(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$) and let $\{\xi_i\}\in l^\infty$.
Let $T:l^1\rightarrow B$ be the linear operator given by: $(Ta)(x) = \sum_n\xi_na_nx^n$.
I have three questions to answer:

1. Show that $\forall a\in l^1$ the function $Ta$ is wel defined and continuous on $[0,1]$.
2. Show that T is bounded
3. Calculate the norm of $T$.

I have thought about this problem for some time and I have some questions/answers in need of verification:

First define $M\equiv\sup_i\xi_i$ (which exists as $\{\xi_i\}\in l^{\infty}$) and define $L\equiv\sum_i|a_i|$ (which also exists).

1. I guess I should show that the sum converges for all $x\in[0,1]$. I would say that this is fairly easy:
   $$
   |\sum_n\xi_na_nx^n| \leq\sum_n|\xi_na_nx^n| \leq M\sum_n |a_nx^n|\leq ML
   $$
   Is that correct? I have no clue how to show that $Ta$ is a continuous function here.
2. For this I am fairly certain:
   $$
   \|T\|_{op}=\sup_{\|a\|_1=1}\|Ta\|_\infty=\sup_{\|a\|_1=1}\sup_{x\in[0,1]}
   |(Ta)(x)| \leq \sup_{\|a\|_1=1}\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\sum_n|\xi_na_nx^n|\leq M,
   $$
   so T is bounded and continuous.
3. I have the feeling that I should have $\|T\|_{op} = M = \sup_i\xi_i$, but I do not know how to prove the inequality the other way around as above. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Detail: you have a typo in 1. It should be $a$, not $x$.

Comment: @julien Thanks! Changed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it should be $M=\sup |\xi_i|$.

For 2.: Yes.

For 1.: You're doing good, you've shown that $Ta$ is well-defined, and 2. at the same time. Now see $Ta(x)$ as the limit of the partial sums. Each partial sum is clearly continuous. So it suffices that the convergence be uniform. Take the remainder and do the same kind of estimate you've done to prove well-definedness. This will show uniform convergence easily.

For 3.: So you've already shown that $\|T\|\leq M=\sup |\xi_i|$. For the reverse inequality, first observe that you can assume $M>0$, for otherwise $T=0$. Now fix $\epsilon>0$ and take $n_0$ such that $|\xi_{n_0}|\geq (1-\epsilon)M$. Then set $a_n=0$ for all $n\neq n_0$ and $a_{n_0}=1$. You have $a\in\ell^1$, $\|a\|_1=1$, and $Ta(1)=\xi_{n_0}$. So $\|Ta\|_\infty\geq (1-\epsilon)M$, hence $\|T\|\geq (1-\epsilon)M$. Now let $\epsilon$ tend to $0$.